# reuse panel with fields across multiple forms in wicket, posible?

Tags: wicket, panel, reusability

i have the following classes :

```
class Address
{ 
  String street; String street2; String number; 
  /*.....other fields, getters and setters*/  
}

class Person
{ 
    /*person specific fields*/
    Address address;
}

class User
{ 
  /* user specific fields */
  Person owner; 
}
```

and i need to make 2 forms one for `Person` and one for `User` , since im using wicket, it seems logical that i could make an `AddressFieldsPanel` with all the fields of an address and use that panel inside `PersonForm` and `UserForm` markup but, wich model should i use to be able to bind the address fields to the `address` property of the `Person` class and also to the `owner.address` of the `User` class, is this posible in wicket?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to try making a `FormComponentPanel`.  I don't know a good public example for this, but there are definitely uses of it in wicket-datetime, and you can get the source for that [here](http://grepcode.com/snapshot/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.apache.wicket/wicket-datetime/1.4.10).

Comment: well looks like that was the answer, making "AddressFieldsPanel" a "FormComponentPanel" certainly gives the desired effect and can be resused to bind to any "Address" object of any class